# Problem with installing package metre

Tags: packages, installing, metre

I am using MikTeX.
I am trying to install the package metre. Unfortunately I always get errors. I have done exactly what is said in the readme file on CTAN, but when trying to run my file, I get the following error message:

```
! Argument of \mathaccentV has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.1619 \edef\Breve{\breve}
                          
?
```

I do not know what to do with this. My document does not even have 1619 lines, I only have 261.
Does anyone know how I might fix this issue and use the package metre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the error with the minimal document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{metre}
```

I don't think it's sensible to use `amsmath` and `metre` in the same document.